# DelphiXE4 64-bit VCL Platform Growing Pains - How to set 64-bit paths?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I recently upgraded from Delphi 2010 to Delphi XE4, but the paths to the source files on one application I am working on are not found by the compiler.  I go to Tools-Project-Options and select the Platform as 64-bit Windows and add the paths to the source files to the Library path.  I close the dialog and try to compile but the paths are not found.  I reopen project options and find that it has reset itself to 32-bit windows.

What is causing the dialog to not set the paths and revert to 32-Bit Windows?
The some files are found, but some are not.  The files that are not found are the 64-bit Abbrevia
files and the 32-bit Abbrevia files.

I have successfully created other 64-bit apps without this problem, so I an confused as to what is going on.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "the paths are not found" means? What is the exact error you're getting? There is no `Tools-Project-Options`. To add a 64-bit target, you go to the Project Manager, right-click on the `Target Platforms`, and choose `Add Platform`, and select `64-bit Windows` from the list. To edit search paths, expand the 'Build Configurations' tree, right-click on the Debug or Release, and choose `Edit...` from the bottom of the menu.

Comment: Why do you have different source paths for 32 bit and 64 bit. That alone sounds wrong. Normally you don't set different values for 32 bit and 64 bit targets. In the base target you use `$(Platform)` which gets expanded to `Win32` or `Win64` as applicable.

Comment: Thanks for responding... I finally got it to build in 64-bit.  There is only one set of source files, but there is a Win32 and Win64 folder for Abbrevia that contains obj files though.

Comment: Oh good. Make use of $(Platform) if ever you need to write Win32/Win64.